# What is the meaning of matrix of an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition, inner-products

In Hoffmann Kunze's *Linear algebra* there is a problem that states:

> Define an inner product on $\mathbb R^2$ by $(\alpha,\beta) = x_1 y_1 -x_2 y_1 - x_1 y_2 + 4 x_2 y_2$ and $\scr B$ be the standard ordered basis of $\mathbb R^2$. Find the matrix of the inner product relative to standard ordered basis.

My question is what do they mean by matrix of an inner product,they did not define it anywhere.Can someone please help me with the meaning of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathscr B=\{e_1,e_2\}$, then the matrix is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}(e_1,e_1)&(e_1,e_2)\\(e_2,e_1)&(e_2,e_2)\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: I just found that they define the matrix to be $G$ such that $G_{j,k}=(\alpha_k,\alpha_j)$